# How to resize image inside cell on JTable?

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable

I would like to resize an image inside a cell on `JTable`.
I am using that code to print the image, it works but without resizing.

```
do {
    Object[] fila = new Object[numcolumnas];
    for (int i = 0; i < numcolumnas; i++) {
        fila[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);

        byte[] imagedataCover = rs.getBytes("Poster");
        format = new ImageIcon(imagedataCover);

        fila[0] = new JLabel(format);

    }
    model.addRow(fila);
    setAnchoColumnas();
} while (rs.next());
```

Comment: First figure out how to resize an image, no table involved.  If still having problems. 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Comment: Thanks .Andrew Thompson.

Comment: What does resizing mean to you? Do you just want an image at a fixed size to fit in the table, or do you want the image to dynamically scale to fill the width of the column as the column width changes?

Comment: Hi camickr,i want a fixed size with the width and height of the cell.

Comment: @user3325719, what if the user changes the width of the cell? Do you want the image to stretch/shrink as the width changes? Or did you disable the column resize functionality.

Comment: resize column is disabled.